# if I don't return anything after if statement in if-else ladder; what will be the default return value?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

suppose I write a if-else statement like this :

```
      const dropItem = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-content67');
        dropItem.forEach((dItem) => {
            let hideIcon = dItem.querySelector('.hide-icon67');
            hideIcon.addEventListener('click', () => {
                dropItem.forEach((dItem2) => {
                    if (dItem !== dItem2) {
                        dItem2.classList.remove('showMenu')
                    }
                })
                if (dItem.classList.contains('showMenu')) {
                    dItem.classList.remove('showMenu')
                }
                else {
                    dItem.classList.add('showMenu')
                }
            })
        })
```

**now I want to find the return value for below portion**

```
dropItem.forEach((dItem2) => {
                    if (dItem !== dItem2) {
                        dItem2.classList.remove('showMenu')
                    }
                })
```

Comment: I see no returns. I am not sure what you are really asking.

Comment: Also you reinvented toggle. `dItem.classList.toggle('showMenu');`

Comment: As always, the default return value in JS is `undefined`. I’m not sure where you expect to see any specific “default return value”. `forEach` doesn’t return anything and discards return values in side of it. `DOMTokenList.prototype.remove` also returns nothing.

Comment: Also what the OP does is subscribing to each drop item individually its own click handler. Thus already for being a handler it does not make any sense to return something from it.

Comment: @ArijitMaiti ... can the OP please explain in detail the use case which makes her/him think to depend on a return value from a callback function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) the return value of `Array.forEach()` will be `undefined` no matter what the callback function returns.

Comment: okay got it; thanks bro